# query a number of rows in sqlite ordered data faster?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a sqlite db that data are ordered by one string field. And i want to retrieve a number of row that begin from a certain, by dictionary order of string field. Now i'm use LIMIT query, but i'm not satisfied with speed. I think search only the first, and then tell sqlite get number of row follow is better, how i can do like that? (My english is not good, sorry if i wrong)

Comment: Also, your 0% accept don't really motivate people to answer...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you mean but I will try to answer. Sorry by advance if I am out of the track.

Let consider that your string column is called mystring. If you want to have good performance when selecting with a specific order, you have to have an index on the column you want to sort.

Your query will look like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY mystring
LIMIT 5,10
```

That is the fastest solution to do it.

Comment: Fastest of **what**, exactly? You don't know anything about the data, what the query is actually asking for, how the indexes are defined, or anything else that would let you say what's "the fastest".

Comment: +1 to say that my answer is inaccurate, potentially wrong and the lack of details of the question does not allow us to understand the problem. However, I presume that the author is a beginner and is looking for a very basic answer. I agree that maybe I am wrong.